# Scala-arm import error: missing arguments for method resource

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-arm

I've added scala-arm to my Play project but got compile error:

[image]

Can't understand what is wrong. Import line was taken from docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `resource` is defined as some kind of function in your code. If this is inside a REPL I would start over. If this is from source file, I would try adding the import at the top of the file.

Comment: You are right. Moving import to the top of the file helped. Thanks